# Capturing undo/redo key events on NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, events, macos, nstableview, undo

I need to capture undo/redo key commands in an NSTableView and forward that down to a managed object context's undo manager.  I have tried overriding -keyDown, but that's hard to navigate.  I really need an internationalized solution to this problem that doesn't revolve around checking for the "z" key with the command key modifier mask.

Is there a way I can set up my tableview to look for the standard "undo" key binding?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement windowWillReturnUndoManager in the delegate of the window containing your NSTableView. Then return your object context's undo manager there. Then your table view will be able to receive those events.

```
[NSWindowDelegate windowWillReturnUndoManager:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You generally use NSUndoManager in Cocoa apps for handling Undo/Redo events. For more information, refer to http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Yeah.  I need to get the undo key command to the managedObjectcontext's undo manager.